# How to ensure that changes of the test object properties do not propagate to other test cases?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

This is `foo.js`:

```
var Foo;

Foo = function () {
    var foo = {};
    foo.get = function (url) {
        // [..]
        return Foo.get(url);
    };
    return foo;
};

Foo.get = function (url) {};

module.exports = Foo;
```

This is a test case for `foo.js`:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect,
    sinon = require('sinon');

describe('foo', function () {
    var Foo,
        foo;
    beforeEach(function () {
        Foo = require('foo.js');
        foo = Foo();
    });
    describe('.get(url)', function () {
        it('passes the call to Foo.get(url)', function () {
            var spy = sinon.spy();

            // We are going to spy on Foo.get:
            Foo.get = spy;

            foo.get('http://');
            // [..]
        });
        it('does something else', function () {
            foo.get('http://');

            // Here Foo.get persists to refer to an instance of sinon.spy.
            // How to make sure that the tests are indepeondent?
        });
    });
});
```

I have overwritten the `Foo.get` property to spy on it.

I expect that using `beforeEach` to `require('foo.js')` will overwrite the `Foo` object and make the next test unaware of the previous changes to the object.

The obvious solution is to store reference to the previous property state and restore it after test, e.g.

```
it('passes the call to Foo.get(url)', function () {
    var spy = sinon.spy(),
        Fooget = Foo.get;

    // We are going to spy on Foo.get:
    Foo.get = spy;

    foo.get('http://');
    // [..]

    Foo.get = Fooget;
});
```

However, this approach is error-prone.

One way of doing it is to rewrite the module & turn it into a constructor:

```
module.exports = function () {
    var Foo;

    Foo = function () {
        var foo = {};
        foo.get = function (url) {
            // [..]
            return Foo.get(url);
        };
        return foo;
    };

    Foo.get = function (url) {};
};
```

And then construct a new instance before each test:

```
describe('foo', function () {
    var Foo,
        foo;
    beforeEach(function () {
        Foo = require('foo.js')();
        foo = Foo();
    });
    describe('.get(url)', function () {
        // [..]
    });
});
```

Not ideal though, because this affects the API of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So sinon has restoration of spies/stubs/mocks built in. It is best to let sinon cleanup after itself instead of trying to manually implement your own cleanup code. With mocha, there is even   [mocha-sinon](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mocha-sinon) which will do the cleanup for you. The mocha-sinon docs also explain how to use a sinon sandbox to keep track of what needs cleaning up and clean it up, but if you use mocha-sinon and do `this.sinon` in your mocha test code, the sandbox creation and cleanup happen automatically for you.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');

beforeEach(function() {
  this.sinon = sinon.sandbox.create();
});

afterEach(function(){
  this.sinon.restore();
});
```

Comment: How can sinon restore the property value of `Foo.get`?

Comment: Use this syntax: `this.sinon.spy(Foo, "get")`. In that way since it knows the string property name, it can restore it to the unspied version.